# Hardware to run ROS on a PC?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is any external hardware ( like a USB camera ) required to run ROS on a PC ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252832/hardware-to-run-ros-on-a-pc-?/) by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2017-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS itself does not 'need' any sensors, as it is a framework that programs and drivers can communicate on rather than a program.

If you want your robot to interact with the world, then yes your robot needs sensors. In general the more sensors, the better. If you only want to simulate the robot, you can with RVIZ and Gazebo (or [turtlesim](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlesim) for starters).

---

Originally posted by [petern3](https://answers.ros.org/users/28607/petern3/) with karma: 186 on 2017-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1